# SCRIPT5039: Redeclaration of const property using IE9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9

I am optimizing my website across IE browsers. Everything works fine except for IE9.

I have a function similar to this one:

```
 var history = new Array();


 function loadPage(page, parameters) {

    $(".dynamic_load").fadeOut(400, function(){

    $(this).fadeIn(400).html("loading").load(page, parameters,
    function(response){
    $(".dynamic_load").html(response).show();  });

                if (history.length > 5) {
                    history.shift();
                } 
                history.push(page); 

                                          });

 }
```

and I am getting an error SCRIPT5039: Redeclaration of const property , which indicates on line

```
 var history = new Array();
```

What does it mean? I haven't declared it anywhere else. It is just a global array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is probably conflicting with [window.history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.history). Rename it to something else and see if the error goes away.

Comment: @epescarello I have the same problem but The variable is not conflicting for sure to anything but I get the same error . Could you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30130131/redeclaration-of-const-property-windows-phone-ie

Answer (score 1):

Btw: Using `screen` as variable name in IE9 causes the same issue.