# What's const property on IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, window, constants

I have got an error in IE10.

```
SCRIPT5039: Redeclaration of const property
```

I deleted `const` property `window` and `document` which I set by `var`.

But the error is still occurred.

So I want to know if there are other `const` property on `IE`.
Or if you have other answers about this error, please tell me.

I delete below code

```
var window
var document
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by the answer to ["SCRIPT5039: Redeclaration of const property" in IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10368057/script5039-redeclaration-of-const-property-in-ie9) it seems that IE does not correctly identify the line where this error happens. So I think the only thing you can do is check some more variable names that might be conflicting.

[SCRIPT5039: Redeclaration of const property using IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9676882/script5039-redeclaration-of-const-property-using-ie9) suggests that you might e.g. be using `history` as a var name. If that is not the case, try checking all properties of the `window` and `document` elements and see which conflict with your variables in the global scope.

It might also be possible that this error message is faulty and caused by IE trying to render the page in Quirks Mode (see [JS error 'redeclaration' of var when it's first line in program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7578163/js-error-redeclaration-of-var-when-its-first-line-in-program/8870698#8870698)). The fix to that should be to fix your script to be standards compatible.

Comment: Thank you for detail information.
I found the criminal navigation.
Thank you so much!!

Comment: @hoshipeace Mind telling us what the offending code was so that people looking for this question might see the solution?

Comment: It's nice. The offending code was "navigator."
Where the best to add this comment? Is here OK?